# Find the index of points closest to each other in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, distance, indexof, euclidean-distance

I have been having trouble implementing the function in order to find the closest point, I've tried multiple ways of doing it but I just can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas on how I should go about solving it?

Euclidean distance

```
def dist(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    dis = sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    return dis
```

Function

```
def offices_to_merge(points):
    min_p1 = 0
    min_p2 = 1
    for i in range(len(points)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(points)):
            dis = dist(points[i], points[j])
            if dis < min((dis)) :
               min_p1 = i
               min_p2 = j
    return (min_p1, min_p2)
```

```
>>> points = [(350, 150), (500, 250), (150, 150), (50, 400), (200, 100)]
>>> offices_to_merge(points)
(2, 4)
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: User `scipy.spatial.KDTree` instead of implementing it yourself.

Comment: In the line `if dis < min((dis))` this `min((dis))` doesn't make a sense. You don't keep a track of current minimal distance.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for providing their own take on the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is, that you don't keep track of current minimal distance observed when iterating through points:

```
def dist(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    dis = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)**0.5
    return dis

def offices_to_merge(points):
    current_minimum = float('inf')
    min_p1 = -1
    min_p2 = -1
    for i in range(len(points)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(points)):
            dis = dist(points[i], points[j])
            if dis < current_minimum:
               min_p1 = i
               min_p2 = j
               current_minimum = dis
    return (min_p1, min_p2)

points = [(350, 150), (500, 250), (150, 150), (50, 400), (200, 100)]
print( offices_to_merge(points) )
```

Prints:

```
(2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cdist` to get all distances between all `points`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

points = [(350, 150), (500, 250), (150, 150), (50, 400), (200, 100)]

# calculate all distances between two sets of points
dists = cdist(points, points)
# the self distance is 0 -> we don't want this so make it large
dists[dists == 0] = dists.max()

# get index of smallest distance
np.unravel_index(dists.argmin(), dists.shape)
>>> (2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combinations to look at all possible pairs of locations. Then you compute all the distances, take the min, and determine the index of the pair that produced that min.

```
from numpy import sqrt
from itertools import combinations

def dist(p1, p2):
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    dis = sqrt((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)
    return dis

points = [(350, 150), (500, 250), (150, 150), (50, 400), (200, 100)]

a = list(combinations(points, 2)) # combinations
b = [dist(el1,el2) for el1,el2 in a] # distances
idx = b.index(min(b)) # index of the min
print(a[idx])
```

Comment: Oh I never knew about combinations thanks for bringing that to my attention, definitely gonna look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If your list of points is large, a brute force approach that pairs up every point having an O(N^2) time complexity will quickly become a performance bottleneck.

There is a way to get the result in O(NlogN) time by sorting the points based on their distance to an arbitrary base point that is smaller than all other points (i.e. below and to the left).   With this sorted approach, the paring of points can be restricted to only those that are within range of the shortest distance found so far.

Here is an example:

```
def dist(a,b): return ((a[0]-b[0])**2 + (a[1]-b[1])**2)**0.5
def nearest2(points):
    minP1,minP2  = points[:2]
    minDist      = dist(minP1,minP2)
    base         = tuple(map(min,zip(*points)))
    sPoints      = sorted((dist(base,p),p) for p in points)
    iMin         = 0
    for ix,(xDist,px) in enumerate(sPoints[1:],1):
        for i,(iDist,pi) in enumerate(sPoints[iMin:ix],iMin):
            if iDist + minDist <= xDist: iMin = i+1; continue
            if dist(px,pi) >= minDist: continue
            minP1,minP2   = px,pi
            minDist       = dist(minP1,minP2)
    return minP1,minP2
```

This function will return two points that are closer to each other than any other pair of points in the list. *Note that, if the dist() function was a 3D distance calculation, the nearest2() function would work for a list of points in 3 dimensions*

```
print(nearest2(points))
((200, 100), (150, 150))
```

For comparison purposes, here is what a brute force approach might look like (similar to your function):

```
def bruteForce(points):
    minP1,minP2 = points[:2]
    minDist     = dist(minP1,minP2)
    for i,p1 in enumerate(points[:-1]):
        for p2 in points[i+1:]:
            if dist(p1,p2) >= minDist: continue
            minP1,minP2 = p1,p2
            minDist     = dist(minP1,minP2)
    return minP1,minP2
```

Measuring the performance difference (for 1000 points) illustrates the benefit of the sort based approach:

```
from random import randint
from timeit import timeit
count = 1
points = list(set( (randint(0,10000),randint(0,10000)*10) for _ in range(1000)))

t = timeit(lambda:nearest2(points),number=count)
print("nearest2  ",t) # 0.0022362289999999785

t = timeit(lambda:bruteForce(points),number=count)
print("bruteForce",t) # 0.36930638299999996
```

*That is more than 150 times faster and, as you add more points, the difference increases even more*

If you need the indexes in the list instead of the points themselves, you could adapt the nearest2() function or wrap it in a fonction that finds the index from the resulting pair of points:

```
def nearest2Index(points):
    p1,p2 = nearest2(points) # bruteForce(points)
    iP1 = points.index(p1)
    iP2 = points.index(p2)
    if iP1 == iP2: iP2 += points[iP1+1:].index(p2) + 1
    if iP1>iP2: iP1,iP2 = iP2,iP1
    return iP1,iP2

points = [(350, 150), (500, 250), (150, 150), (50, 400), (200, 100)]
print(nearest2Index(points)) # (2,4)
```